# Issue trying to preform a delete with php and angular

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to preform a delete with angular and php. I am pretty sure that my php is right.

But i am not able to delete. In my console log it says that my deletion was succesfull but when looking in the table I still see the recored.

Upon further inspection with debugger in chrome I see dat my parameter index is undefined -> http://gyazo.com/88b6dcf9d4c03a1fc9dd235303b20a8f

(part of) My HTML code:

```
<md-button  class="md-primary" ng-click="delete_task(task.id)">Delete</md-button>
```

(part of) My app.js file:

```
/** function to delete a task from list referencing php **/
        $scope.delete_task = function(index) {  
            debugger;
            $http.post('db.php?action=delete_task', 
                {
                    'task_index' : index
                }
            )      
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {   
                // here we also replace how to get the user
                getTaskFunction( 
                    /* success function */ 
                    function(data) { 
                        $scope.taskInfo = data; 
                       console.log("The taks have been reloaded" , $scope.taskInfo);
                    }, 
                    /* error function */ 
                    function() 
                    { 
                        alert("Server load failed"); 
                    } 
                );
                console.log('Deletion was succesfull');
            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
               console.log("You were NOT succesfull in deleting a task"); 
            }
        );
```

(part of) My PHP code:

```
<?php
    include('config.php');

    switch($_GET['action'])  {
        case 'get_ProjectType_Info' :
            get_ProjectType_Info();
            break;
        case 'add_task' :
            add_task();
            break;
        case 'get_Location_Info' :
            get_Location_Info();
            break;
        case 'get_Task_Info' :
            get_Task_Info();
            break;
        case 'delete_task' :
            delete_task();
            break;
    }

    /**  Function to delete a task   **/
    function delete_task() {
        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
        $index = $data->task_index;
        echo ($index);
        //print_r($data);
        $del = mysql_query("DELETE FROM tblTask WHERE id = ".$index);
        if($del)
        return true;
        return false;
    }
```

I am not sure how to proceed from this point on.

Comment: If the index is missing then your parameter "task.id" is probably wrong. Print it out and see what its value is. You may also trigger a delete manually in scope by calling $scope.delete_task("a known id") and see if it works. If it does then the function and backend are OK and your parameter is wrong

Comment: @RainerPlumer, I just add $scope.delete_task(100); after my delete function? when i log my index in the delete function then it shows but repeats constantly -> http://gyazo.com/ee08c8c0cbc00c711c40abbb92a3730c

Comment: yep, then...if the delete works as expected, you know that your "task.id" is the problem, and the rest works.

Comment: wait now when i just log the index like so console.log(index); it shows that its undefined -> http://gyazo.com/8923f8b1df132108a1b9f8ca6a843792

Comment: It shouldnt say "undefined" once you hardcode that test value. Make sure your browsers cache is disabled, and angular is re-loading your templates/code.

Also, a more serious bug in your code is actually this
"$del = mysql_query("DELETE FROM tblTask WHERE id = ".$index);"
Never pass variables like this into your queries....even a beginner hacker could wipe out your database fairly easily. Use mysql_real_escape_string or typecast to (int)

Comment: ok i have done both your test: the logging of the index which returns undefined and the manual deleting. the manual deleting works. so the issue is with this index parameter. don't know how to fix it .... Thanks for the php tip, will change it after i get the deletion working

Comment: Well, since the problem is the "task.id" parameter being undefined, trace it and see where it gets its value( or should get its value but isnt ).

Comment: it gets its value from the scope where the scope retrieves it from php. in my php i am doing an echo($index); but its not showing the echo anywhere ...

Answer (score 0):

It should be better not use querystring variables together with post variables as you're doing. Create a complete object on javascript statement in order to have something like this:

```
{
    'task_index' : index,
    action: 'delete_task'
 }
```

And then you should threat this object data inside you switcher.

It would be great if you adopt some practices that take the code cleaner and easier to understand.

First thing of all, you should test your `delete_task` method. To make it successfully I suggest you to get the variables calling `file_get_contents("php://input"))` into the switch and passing them as method parameters. Make it this way:

```
<?php
   // ...
   // Receive id you have already collected
   function delete_task($task_id){        
    $del = mysql_query("DELETE FROM tblTask WHERE id = ".$task_id);
    if($del) return true;
    return false;
   }

   // test that method
   function test_delete(){
     $ret = delete_task(4);   // test with valid and invalid ids 
   }
 ?>
```

Obviously this is not a beautiful way to test methods and you should consider using any test framework for unit tests. But it's important to build methods in a way that you can change parameters and observe its behavior. Once you are assured that this method (the more critic one in this scenery) is working, you can go down one level on stack and check if your switcher is working well. At this time you can test your endpoint using [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) for Chrome, as an example.